# Do I own the copyright of a source code if I work only part of it as a freelancer

Tags: copyright, contract-law, intellectual-property, software

If a group of freelancers work on a project without a contract from the client(this one refuses to pay), who own the copyright of that source code? I know in the US, one who write the code own the copyright unless specifically indicate in the contract.

Comment: I see your profile says Haiti, but as laws vary around the world which jurisdiction (country, province, state, principality etc) does this actually relate to?

Comment: The client is in the USA

Comment: For your question about multiple people contributing (group of freelancers), see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50874/copyright-and-pair-programming